# How can I update the hash sent from view without ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

Working in Rails 4. I have a from that the user submits to update an object called Flow. I have a Rich Many-To_many association between Flows and Locations. Flows can have many locations, but when they do I need to keep track of if the location is a source or destination.

To do this, I have a form that asks the user to choose the source locations and then the destination locations. In my controller, I save the proper locations with the proper additional properties into the join table.

Then I remove the locations from the prams hash and submit the rest of the params to the @flow.update.

When I do this I get an error: **ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError**

I dont understand why this is, All of the required fields are listed in my params.permit. 
It seems like Rails simply wont let me touch the hash that comes back from the view, or it becomes forbidden. How do I get around this? Any suggestions?

Flows_controller.rb

```
  def update
    @flow_id = params['id']
    @flow = Flow.find(@flow_id)
    old_flow_locs = @flow.flow_locations

    @source_loc_ids = params['flow']['source_location_ids']
    @source_loc_ids.reject!(&:empty?)
    @source_loc_ids.uniq!
    @source_loc_ids.each do |src_loc_id|

    flow_loc = FlowLocation.new()
    flow_loc.source = 'TRUE'
    flow_loc.flow_id = @flow_id
    flow_loc.location_id = src_loc_id
    flow_loc.save!
end

@dest_loc_ids = params['flow']['destination_location_ids']
@dest_loc_ids.reject!(&:empty?)
@dest_loc_ids.uniq!
@dest_loc_ids.each do |dst_loc_id|
  flow_loc = FlowLocation.new()
  flow_loc.destination = 'TRUE'
  flow_loc.flow_id = @flow_id
  flow_loc.location_id = dst_loc_id
  flow_loc.save!
end

# delete old flow locations
old_flow_locs.each do |x|
  x.destroy
end

@updated_flow_params = params['flow'].except('source_location_ids').except('destination_location_ids')



respond_to do |format|
  if @flow.update(@updated_flow_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @flow, notice: 'Flow was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @flow }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @flow.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

```
def flow_params
  params.require(:flow).permit(:title, :description, :source_id, :company_id, :service_id, :destination_id, :status, :source_location_ids, :destination_location_ids, :status_details)
end
```

The Params coming in from my view look like this:

```
{
"utf8": "✓",
"authenticity_token": "mkHsRahEh4Y7sUsEW+WgEYEWaM37WY7w4jkZbnRTZV6y6T7WWe2/s+oQYxvpRkx8GEqSxNxcLw9ZpKoT5s7AwQ==",
"flow": {
    "title": "Direct Transfer Intuitive to DASH Cloud",
    "company_id": "1",
    "service_ids": [
        "",
        "4"
    ],
    "source_location_ids": [
        "",
        "3"
    ],
    "destination_location_ids": [
        "",
        "2",
        "1"
    ]
},
"commit": "Update Flow",
"id": "16"
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of the error stacktrace? It should tell you which param is not permitted. I assume it could be `id` ? If yes permit that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to permit arrays in the parameter like this:

```
source_location_ids: []
```

So in your case you could try:

```
def flow_params
  params.require(:flow).permit(:title, :description, :source_id, :company_id, :destination_id, :status, :status_details, source_location_ids: [], destination_location_ids: [], :service_ids: [])
end
```

Also you were only permitting `service_id` while the params hash shows an array of `service_ids`.